# Error trying to use a4j:mediaOutput on JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to render a picture in my application. I have choosen a4j:mediaOutput to render that. I use the example from the jboss doc [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Resources.html#sect-Component_Reference-Resources-mediaOutput) and it shows the error:

> 11:49:53,716 SEVERE  [org.richfaces.log.Resource] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9080-25) Input error for deserialize data : java.io.InvalidClassException: Unauthorized deserialization attempt; simple.MediaData
>       at org.richfaces.util.LookAheadObjectInputStream.resolveClass(LookAheadObjectInputStream.java:100) [richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1695) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1600) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1875) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2094) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2019) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1902) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1432) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1789) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1426) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceUtils.decodeObjectData(ResourceUtils.java:247) [richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]
>       at org.richfaces.resource.DefaultCodecResourceRequestData.getData(DefaultCodecResourceRequestData.java:96) [richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]
>       at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceFactoryImpl.createResource(ResourceFactoryImpl.java:325) [richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]
>       at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:111) [richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:400) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:355) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:936) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$DefaultThreadFactory$1$1.run(NioEndpoint.java:1249) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) [vm.jar:1.8.0]
>
> 11:49:53,724 ERROR 
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/outputmediaTest].[Faces
>   Servlet]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9080-25) JBWEB000236:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.richfaces.resource.MediaOutputResource.encode(MediaOutputResource.java:65)
>   [richfaces-a4j-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]     at
>   org.richfaces.resource.UserResourceWrapperImpl.encode(UserResourceWrapperImpl.java:187)
>   [richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]    at
>   org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:184)
>   [richfaces-core-4.5.17.Final.jar:4.5.17.Final]    at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:400)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:355)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:911)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$ChannelProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:936)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   [rt.jar:1.8.0]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$DefaultThreadFactory$1$1.run(NioEndpoint.java:1249)
>   [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) [vm.jar:1.8.0]

When I change MediaData to implements org.richfaces.resource.SerializableResource rather than Serializable, it starts to say awt.Color can't be serialized.

To be clear, my xhtml file is:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
<h:form id="form">
<h1>TEST</h1>
<a4j:mediaOutput element="img" cacheable="false" id="img" createContent="#{mediaBean.paint}"
        value="#{mediaData}" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
</h:form>
```

and my POM.xml is:

```
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.leandrolima</groupId>
<artifactId>outputmediaTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>outputmediaTest</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec/jboss-javaee-6.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces/richfaces-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces/richfaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
```

I am using JBoss EAP 6.4 and also tried with Tomcat 8.0 with jsf impl:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

the error is the same.

Comment: According to the stack trace the "createContent" is null, which is weird. Have you tried running the showcase?

Comment: Are you meaning this one http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=mediaOutput ? They use a mediaReader and doesn't show the code.

Comment: I tryed showcase using the code in this page https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=richfaces-master/examples/showcase/src/main/java/org/richfaces/demo/mediaOutput/MediaReader.java# and the error is the same. I'll edit the post to say it.

Comment: I don't mean copying the code, I mean deploying the showcase locally, if it doesn't work then it's probably something with your server. What server are you running anyway?

Comment: I'm using JBoss EAP 6.4 and have tried with Tomcat with jsf implementation from oracle also.

Answer (score 2):

Well the first exception is rather important.

The @value has to be either a basic data type or implement one of the [white-listed classes](https://github.com/richfaces/richfaces/blob/4.5.17.Final/core/src/main/resources/org/richfaces/resource/resource-serialization.properties)

Comment: Hi Makhiel I know that. Thanks for the answre, but I also have said in the question that I've tried implement SerializableResource and it started to say that awt.Date is not serializable.

Comment: What's the error message? The one I'm seeing when using java.awt.Color is the same as above.

Comment: exactly, the same. The problem is that the official example is wrong.

Comment: You can also add classes to the whitelist by creating your own **`resource-serialization.properties`** file. But I wouldn't recommend that since it can increase the possibility of security vulnerabilities: https://codewhitesec.blogspot.com/2018/05/poor-richfaces.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found that making the mediaData implement SerializableResource solves the first error, as Makhiel have said. With some workaround it worked and shown the image.

To help others trying to see the component working, since the official showcase seems not be functional, follows a simple example. Just with the MediaBean:

```
package simple;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

@ManagedBean(name = "imageBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MediaBean {
    private static final String RICHFACES_MEDIA_OUTPUT_IMAGE_SOURCE = "/images/image.jpg";

    public void paint(final OutputStream out, final Object data) throws IOException {
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }

        final byte[] imageData = getImage(Integer.parseInt((String) data));

        final InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
        try {
            final BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
            ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", out);
        }
        finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private byte[] getImage(final int data) throws IOException {
        final ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        final String resource = extContext.getResource(RICHFACES_MEDIA_OUTPUT_IMAGE_SOURCE).getFile();
        final BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File(resource));
        final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

and the xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <rich:panel>
        <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" cacheable="false" session="false"
            createContent="#{imageBean.paint}" value="0" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
    </rich:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Puting the `/images/image.jpg` in webapp folder it should show that image.

Despite that, I countinue receiving the second error message in my work environment.

Researching about, I've found that in the mini project I've create on Tomcat to test, I've used **JSF 2.2.10** and in my work environment I am using JBoss EAP 6.4 that came with **JSF 2.0.3-b05**. In both I am using RichFaces 4.5.17.Final and apparently, that version is incompatible to JSF 2.0.3-b05.

Trying to use that version I receive the error message:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart GRAVE:
>   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! The
>   JSF implementation 2.0.3- does not support the RichFaces
>   ExtendedPartialViewContext.  Please upgrade to at least Mojarra 2.1.28
>   or 2.2.6

The problem started when we started to migrate from JBoss 6.1 to 6.4 and change the RichFaces version. So I believe that is the cause of the problem and the possible solution is to upgrade JSF version.